# Cannot resolve constructor 'GridLayoutManager(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, grid-layout

I am facing this problem when I change the LinearLayoutManagar to GridLayoutManager.
I want the list to be in the grid view not list view.
The error comes in the getActivity()

**error:**

```
no suitable constructor found for GridLayoutManager(FragmentActivity)
    constructor GridLayoutManager.GridLayoutManager(Context,AttributeSet,int,int) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor GridLayoutManager.GridLayoutManager(Context,int) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor GridLayoutManager.GridLayoutManager(Context,int,int,boolean) is not applicable
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

This is my code.

```
public class FragmentBookmark extends Fragment {
    View paramView;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        return paramView;
    }


}
```

My Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
       return new ListViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        ((ListViewHolder) viewHolder).bindView(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return OurData.title.length;
    }

    private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private TextView mItemText;
        private ImageView mItemImage;

        public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mItemText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            mItemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

       public void bindView(int position) {
            mItemText.setText(OurData.title[position]);
            mItemImage.setImageResource(OurData.picture[position]);

       }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

bookmark xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/listRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

grid item xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="newText"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The error message tells you the problem. There is no constructor that takes just a `Context`. You might've also checked [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager#public-constructors) for the available constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with below code. Your code is failing because Constructor expects two params, `Context` -> **Activity context** and `int` - **No of columns**.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), numberOfColumns));
```

Answer (score 1):

[GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html#GridLayoutManager(android.content.Context,%20int)) expects more than one argument, try one of its constructors:

```
int num_columns = 2;
new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), num_columns);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked but I have make like accepted the KaranMer answer because I saw first his code.
Hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

change this line of your code :

```
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity());
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

to

```
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),numberOfYourColumns);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 // Initializing recyclerview
        RecyclerView recyclerViewItems = findViewById(R.id.rv_feeds);
        //setting no of cols. orientation using GridLayoutManager
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerViewItems.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        //passing data to adapter
        FeedsRecycleViewAdapter adapter = new FeedsRecycleViewAdapter(this, myImageList, myBrands, myPrice, myActPrice);
```

Comment: you are not properly initializing the GridLayout chk above reference for your convenience

Answer (score 0):

Add layout manager in bookmark.xml file

`xmlns:app="http://`schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
 app:spanCount="2"`

Remove setLlayoutManager from activity